# Weird output when implementing matlab firpm/firls FIR filter in hardware

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, filter, embedded

I suspect it might be something with the way I've implemented by FIR filter in code. The mainloop looks like this

```
  while (1)
  {

        float y = 0;
        for(uint16_t i = 0; i < FT_ORDER; i++)
        {
            y = y + x[FT_ORDER - i-1] *h[i]; //convolution sum, h is an array with FIR coefficients of length FT_ORDER, in this case 21. 
        }
        for(uint16_t i = 0; i < FT_ORDER-1; i++)
        {
            x[i] = x[i+1]; //shift values in buffer 
        }
        
        

        
        HAL_ADC_Start(&myADC2Handle); // start A/D conversion
        if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&myADC2Handle, 5) == HAL_OK) //check if conversion is completed
        {
        Adc_value  = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&myADC2Handle); // read digital value and save it inside uint32_t variable
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_5)// ignore pin toggles;
        }
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&myADC2Handle); // stop conversion 
        x[20] = Adc_value; //store most recent value in the end of buffer

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    HAL_DAC_SetValue(&DAC_Config, DAC_CHANNEL_2, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, (int)(y)); //output waveform DAC by printing convolution sum y
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14);
    
}
```

[image]
[image]

The results look like these. I'm feeding in a sinewave to my STM32, I think what's happening is the y values is exceeding the maximum limit of DAC and it's just that. But the strange thing is when I use a LPF made by using sinc function, I'm getting the expected waveforms. This thing seems to only be happening with my matlab designed coefficients. Also matlab shows my peak gain to be less then 1, so this is totally unexpected

my matlab code looks like this

```
F = [500 1000 1500 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 5500 6000 6500 7000 7500 8000];
F = F/8000;
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
%A = db2mag(A);
A = A/max(A);
disp(A);
b = firpm(20,F,A);
b= b/2
[H,f] = freqz(b,1,512,2);
plot(f,abs(H))
hold on
for i = 1:2:6, 
   plot([F(i) F(i+1)],[A(i) A(i+1)],'r--')
end
legend('firls design','Ideal')
grid on
xlabel('Normalized Frequency (\times\pi rad/sample)')
ylabel('Magnitude')
fprintf('%i,', b);
```

pretty straightforward code from their website. I even applied a windowing function to the coefficients to stop making it go out of bound this way but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You posted this same question on DSP stackexchange. Please choose one and delete the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the thing always worked with LPF, not just LPFs, but any filter where the DC gain was 1. I realized this line

```
  HAL_DAC_SetValue(&DAC_Config, DAC_CHANNEL_2, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, (int)(y));
```

was driving y negative and was causing some serious weirdness, when I gave y an offset by adding turning it into (int)(y) + 2000, the problem fixed itself since the DAC was not being asked to go to a  negative value anymore. It's still curious what the thing did with the negative value, it made the whole thing go overbounds.